# What is the receiver URL for Chromecast on native chrome for android browser

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to find out what the default receiver URL is for Chromecast when you activate it from Chrome on Android. I am not talking about a custom app but the browser based one that appears if you have a chromecast connected when viewing on chrome for android.

The reason is that my web video project has it's assets ( videos) protected on Amazon S3 with a bucket policy to only allow some http refere URL's.

Now I have tested this and working with JW Player's custom Chromecast integration, they have their own receiver app URL - and if I add that URL to the whitelist in the policy then I can cast this protected content. If I remove the URL it will not cast the video.

Problem is that JW Player chromecast app does not take over on android chrome as it does on a desktop chrome browser. So in it's place is the native chrome browser chromecast button, which of course has a different receiver URL.

I would like to know how to find out what that URL is so I can whitelist it and play content on chromecast

Comment: You can't cast from Android Chrome. Casting from Chrome is done through the cast extension and extensions aren't support in Android Chrome.

Comment: The cat icon shows up so I dont understand why you say you can't. If I make my videos public then I can use the button to cast

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an easy way to figure out what the URL is, but you can try to kick up wireshark and look for requests for videos in JW's domain.

I also think there's a bit of confusion about how Cast works.

Chromecast does not care about where you want to Cast your stuff from. All it cares about is the App Id and then does a bit of magic to translate the App Id into a URL which then does the video stuff. What App Id is used is completely up to the Sender.

If your URL whitelisting is not working, it is likely that the Web Player on Android uses a different App Id than the one that you've whitelisted.

Also, I don't think that there is a "default" player that is automatically included for all video players. It is always a conscious decision on the Developer's part what App Id to use.